# LG G5: Nougat: Your device is corrupt. It cannot be trusted and will not boot

Tags: boot, 7.0-nougat

Stupidly locked boot loader and now device now won't boot.  I didn't realise I was running Nougat so now the verified boot checker prevents device from booting altogether, "Your device is corrupt. It cannot be trusted and will not boot".

All I can do is get get the devices to stock recovery which is pointless as it is not picked up in ADB and I can reset to factory here either.

I don't need to retain any data I just want to get the device working again.  Any tips? Help?

Thanks

xM

Comment: Unlock the bootloader again?

Comment: Why did you locked bootloader that won't bring back waranity because when you lock it for 'bootloader state' it says 'relocked'. Try unlocking bootloader again as owlswipe said.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realise that until now - noob mistake. as GPS is faulty on my phone so wanted to take it back the shop to replace and thought I'd lock the bootloader. I can't get the device to be recognised in ADB to unlock boot loader again... any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
Turn off your LG G5.
With your LG G5 connected by USB to your computer, push volume down and power button on your phone, then release power button keeping volume down pressed.

It *should* boot to bootloader directly.
In this state, you might unlock it with your personal unlock.bin file:

```
fastboot flash unlock unlock.bin
```

Then check if unlock is granted:

```
fastboot getvar unlocked
```

Also, you could flash TWRP recovery from here with:

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp-whicheverversionfits.img
```

If this works, please let us know :)

Comment: This worked a treat!  Only amendment is that I had to power down the phone (removed battery) then hold volume down for 5 seconds then plug in USB - it then boots to fast boot.  I then unlocked OEM as above!